# [PHP]: What does array_search() return if nothing was found?

Tags: php, arrays, search

What does array_search() return if nothing was found?

I have the need for the following logic:

```
$found = array_search($needle, $haystack);

if($found){
  //do stuff
} else {
  //do different stuff
}
```

Comment: It's faster to try it and see the result than asking it.

Comment: check result is_int() seeing as it returns a key..

Comment: @LucM It's faster to google this question than to try it.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Quoting the **manual page of [`array_search()`](http://fr.php.net/array_search)** :

> Returns the key for needle if it is
>   found in the array, **`FALSE` otherwise**.

Which means you have to use something like :

```
$found = array_search($needle, $haystack);

if ($found !== false) {
    // do stuff
    // when found
} else {
    // do different stuff
    // when not found
}
```

Note I used the `!==` operator, that does a type-sensitive comparison ; see [Comparison Operators](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), [Type Juggling](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php), and [Converting to boolean](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) for more details about that ;-)

Comment: `Note I used the !== operator, that does a type-sensitive comparison` - that's exactly what the problem was.  0 was evaluating to false... thanks

Comment: You're welcome :-) ;; I've edited my answer to add links to some other relevant pages of the manual, btw :-)

Comment: It now returns `NULL` instead. You might want to update your answer.

Comment: @AmalMurali - `array_search()` only returns `NULL` if an invalid parameter was supplied, e.g. a variable that is not an array. If you supply valid parameters, it will return `false` if the value is not found in the array.

Comment: @DerekAdair I know the question is quite old, but more information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581619/php-what-does-array-search-return-if-nothing-was-found/58383073#58383073) for future reference.

Answer (score 6):

if you're just checking if the value exists, [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

One has to be *very* careful to distinguish the cases `item found with index 0` and `not found`.

In the first case `array_search` returns the integer `0`, in the second it returns the bool `false`.

⚠ **Danger zone** here because if we don't pay attention, it's easy to have 0 and `false` considered as the same thing in a `if` test. ⚠

If you want to be able to distinguish both, **you have to use `if ($i !== false)`**,
and not `if ($i)` or `if ($i != false)`. Why? See the following example:

Example:

```
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');

$i = array_search('red', $array);   
var_dump($i);                      // int(1)
echo ($i !== false) ? $i : -1;     // 1

$i = array_search('blue', $array); 
var_dump($i);                      // int(0)
echo ($i !== false) ? $i : -1;     // 0      // CORRECT
echo ($i != false) ? $i : -1;      // -1     // WRONG! don't use:  if ($i) ...
echo ($i) ? $i : -1;               // -1     // WRONG! don't use:  if ($i != false) ...

$i = array_search('blueee', $array);
var_dump($i);                      // bool(false)
echo ($i !== false) ? $i : -1;     // -1, i.e. not found
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the official documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php:

> Warning This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on
>   Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the
>   return value of this function.

See this example:

```
$foundKey = array_search(12345, $myArray);
if(!isset($foundKey)){
    // If $myArray is null, then $foundKey will be null too.
    // Do something when both $myArray and $foundKey are null.
} elseif ($foundKey===false) {
    // $myArray is not null, but 12345 was not found in the $myArray array.
}else{
    // 12345 was found in the $myArray array.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> Searches haystack for needle and returns the key if it is found in the array, FALSE otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

array_search will return FALSE if nothing is found. If it DOES find the needle it will return the array key for the needle.

More info at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php